# How to implement the vertical stack transformer in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In vertical viewpager, while swipe in vertically current screen are move to left side but i have to move my second view over the first view (i.e)first view should be fit to the screen.I had implement the vertical stack transformer but its not working fine to me. Can you anyone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

This is viewpager I had used.

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());

    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                view.setAlpha(1);
                view.setTranslationX(0);
                view.setScaleX(1);
                view.setScaleY(1);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]

               // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationY(position < 0 ? 0f : -view.getHeight() * position);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }

}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}
}
```

Here my code I had modified.

```
@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.

                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
                // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
                view.setAlpha(1);
                view.setTranslationX(0);
                view.setScaleX(1);
                view.setScaleY(1);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]

               // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationY(position < 0 ? 0f : -view.getHeight() * position);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            } 
}
```